# electron 9 remote.getCurrentWindow().close() not working

Tags: reactjs, electron

i have a two window application, the first window is created like so:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1024, // width of the window
    height: 768, // height of the window
    show: false, // don't show until window is ready
    frame: false,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        enableRemoteModule: true
    }
})
```

after that user can prompt opening of second window, following function is called

```
import { remote } from "electron";

let dev = require('electron-is-dev');
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

let win

export default function createPopupWindow(currentLanguage) {

    win = new remote.BrowserWindow({
        width: 500,
        height: 700,
        frame: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            enableRemoteModule: true
        }
    });

    win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
        win.webContents.send('message', { language: currentLanguage });
    });


    let indexPath

    // Determine the correct index.html file
    // (created by webpack) to load in dev and production
    if (dev && process.argv.indexOf('--noDevServer') === -1) {
        indexPath = url.format({
            protocol: 'http:',
            host: 'localhost:8080',
            pathname: '/src/editWindow/index.html',
            slashes: true
        })
    } else {
        // todo
        indexPath = url.format({
            protocol: 'file:',
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.jsx'),
            slashes: true
        })
    }

    // Load the index.html
    win.loadURL(indexPath)

    win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        win.show()
    })
}
```

The problem is that after upgrading from electron 8 to 9 I am not able to call the following to close the second window. I have already found that close event is being called, but window is not closing.

```
import { ipcRenderer, remote } from 'electron';
...
remote.getCurrentWindow().close();
```

Thanks in advance!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in electron 9.1.2, finally I found the way to fix it. The point is that you can't retain the window directly on mainProcess.

before in my `main.js`, I have a variable to store the window object, now I change it to store the window.id, and define a helper function to get the window by windowId.

before:

```
let mainWindow;

const createWindow = () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 300,
    height: 440,
    frame: false,
  });
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);
```

after:

```
let mainWindowId = 0

const createWindow = () => {
  let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 300,
    height: 440,
    frame: false,
  });
  mainWindowId = mainWindow.id
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

const getMainWindow = () => {
  return BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().filter(
    (window) => window.id === mainWindowId
  )[0];
};
```